# Custom UIButton class, is there a was clicked event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to make a custom UIButton class called BubbleButton. It will perform some animations when the button is clicked and released. Are there methods that I can put in that will be called when the button is pressed or released? Such as didClicked or something like that?

Comment: Have a look at the UIResponder class for the methods you should override https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder

Comment: I found that using touchesBegan and touchesEnded works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only (really) two that you should be worried about, `setSelected` and `setHighlighted`. setHighlighted is called immediatly after the button is pressed and setSelected is called if you hold the button for like 1/2 a second. There is also a focused state but thats not really relevant. Here is an example of a UIButton I subclasssed:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{ 
  [super drawRect:rect]; 
  //Set unhighlighted state 
  if (self.highlighted) { 
     //Set highlighted state 
 } 
} 
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted { 
  [super setHighlighted:highlighted]; 
  [self setNeedsDisplay]; 
}
```

Comment: How about a release? I'd like to set an animation where it returns to its default state

Comment: Why not listen for the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchDown` events?

Comment: @MarkBourke You should update your answer with code instead of posting it in comments.